# F#: String.Join and |> operator

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

In F# interactive, I can use `String.Join("+", ["a"; "b"])` successfully, but

```
["a"; "b"] |> String.Join "+"
```

produces an error:

```
Script1.fsx(79,15): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string list -> 'a    
but here has type
    string
```

How do I use `String.Join` passing a collection using pipeline?

P.S. The same problem is with `lines |> File.WriteAllLines "filename.txt"`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`String.Join` is a .NET method. When using a .NET method, F# views it as a function that takes a tuple as an argument (when calling it you write parameters as `f(a, b)`). The `|>` operator can be used with functions that use the *curried form* of parameters (and can be called by writing `f a b`).

You can use a function `String.concat` from the F# library (which does the same thing) instead:

```
["a"; "b"] |> String.concat "+"
```

**EDIT** `File.WriteAllLines` is the same case. If you want to use it as part of a pipeline, you can write an F# function that wraps the call:

```
let writeAllLines file (lines:seq<string>) =
  System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines)
```

In general, you can use `|>` with .NET methods only if you want to write all arguments on the left side of the operator. You can for example write:

```
("+", ["a"; "b"]) |> System.String.Join
```

... but that doesn't fit with the usual use of pipeline operator. When working with .NET API, it is usually better to use a C#-like style of programming (without pipelining), because pipeline works well only with functional libraries.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, any luck with `File.WriteAllLines`?

Comment: @modosansreves: I added answers to your other questions.

Comment: I think it has to be ("+",[|"a","b"|]) |> System.String.Join, taking an array of strings. Doesn't really matter though, it still makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: @cfern: I think the original works too, because there is an overload taking `seq<string>`.

Comment: @Tomas Petricek: the IEnumerable overload is only present in .Net 4 (which explains why it didn't work for me in VS2008). I learned something new today. :)

Comment: @cfem: Interesting, thanks for sharing. I learned something too :-)

Comment: I have create a project that is a collection of inline functions around BCL static methods [ComposableExtensions](http://jbtule.github.io/ComposableExtensions/)

Answer (score 24):

I thought I would weigh in with an alternative. The OP specifically asked about String.Join, and Tomas Petricek's answer is absolutely correct for that method (use String.concat from the F# library).

If you're talking about another method that takes tupled arguments but you want to use them as curried, you can use this helper function:

```
let partial f x y = f(x, y)
```

This allows you to pass a method to 'partial' and get back a curried function. Use it like this:

```
let partial f x y = f(x, y)
myCollection |> partial String.Join "&"
```

Comment: A good name for this function might be "curry"; then you could also have "uncurry"